# ruby on rails changing variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a problem in ruby on rails. I want to make current user's store id to be 0 when user accesses to /homepage/, and i want to make user's store id to be the input id in the url when user accesses to /homepage/:id/.

My code:

```
routes.rb:
  match "/homepage" => "users#access", :as => "store"
  match "/homepage/:id" => "users#homepage", :as => "store"

def access
  @user = current_user
  @user.update_attributes(:store => "0")
  @user.save
end

def homepagestore
  @user = current_user
  @user.update_attribute(:id, user.store = :id)
  @user.save
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to upvote ALL useful answers, including those to others' questions. And check/accept the best answers to your questions.

Comment: Can I point out this seems to be unexpected behavior?  If I've gone to /homepage/5 and that's my store, if I accidentally go to /homepage I'll lose access to my store.

What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2):

[update_attribute](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) updates the record in the database. But it skips the validation checks. [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes) also updates (saves) the record in the database. It does not skip validation.

So:

1. You should use `params[:id]` as Sergio says
2. You may want to use `update_attributes` instead since it does not skip validation checks
3. You do NOT need the `save` method if you use `update_attribute` or `update_attributes`

My suggestions:

```
def access
  @user = current_user
  @user.update_attributes(:store => "0")
end

def homepagestore
  @user = current_user
  @user.update_attributes(:store => params[:id])
end
```

**Added** update_attributes uses the mass-assignment protection system. So you need the :store field in your User model's attr_accessible call to allow it to be changed. Or override the protection, see the update_attributes docs. Ask if you have more questions.

Comment: There are some errors when I apply your suggestions. Line 14 is :    @user.update_attributes(:store => "0") [code]undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in `access'[/code]

Comment: Ok, that means that `current_user` is not being set correctly. Or do you have a typo --  update_attributes'  vs update_attributes

Comment: def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

Comment: I added a store column to User table using SQlite manager, and change the model file and added :store to it. Are there any other changes needed in this process?

Comment: Re: current_user. You need to see if the code is working or not. It looks good but maybe something is wrong with the session. Re: adding a new column--did you add :store to the attr_accessible call in the  User model file?

Comment: Yes I've added to the attr_accessible call.

Comment: Next debugging step is to carefully find out what is happening and what is not happening. You can use the debugger if you have it all set up or logging statements if need be. Good luck!